# How to get text at variable positions in Robot Framework

Tags: xpath, robotframework

I'd like to inquire about a syntax question related to the Robot Framework.
The HTML structure is as follows:

```
<div id="testblock">
  <p> </p>
  <p>
    <span class="labelText">Number: </span>
    " >= 2 "
  </p>
  <p> </p>
<div>
```

I want to capture the text " >=2 ", and its position may vary within different

tags. Could you please advise on the correct method to capture it?
Thank you.

Tried the following methods all failed:

```
${text}=    Get Text    xpath=//div[@id="testblock"]//p/span[@class='lableText' and contains(text(), 'Number: ')]/parent::p/following-sibling::p
${text}=    Get Text    xpath=//div[@id="testblock"]//p/span[@class='lableText' and contains(text(), 'Number: ')]/following-sibling::p
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you do it in two steps:

1. Find the nearest parent web element that contains all necessary text
2. Take the `text` property from it.

For example:

```
    ${testblock} =   get webelement   //*[@id="testblock"]
    ${my_text} =     set variable     ${testblock.text}
    log to console   ${my_text}
```

Outputs:   **Number: " >= 2 "**

Answer (score 0):

The xpath should be:

```
//div[@id="testblock"]/p/span[@class='labelText' and contains(text(), 'Number: ')]/following-sibling::text()
```

There is issue with the value of span `class`

The value in your xml=`labelText`

and in your xpath=`lableText`